# Can systemd-journald use network to transmit?

Tags: systemd-journald

I use systemd-journald and forwards the log messages to rsyslog on my centos host , and then use rsyslog transmit on network .

So, Can systemd-journald transmit log message use network?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/635001/forward-systemd-journal-messages-collect-systemd-journal-messages, https://serverfault.com/questions/758244/how-to-configure-systemd-journal-remote